# OMP parallel nested for cycles

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to multiply two n by n matrices using omp in C.
But my code only calculates the diagonal elements. Here is the code:

My code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <omp.h>

int main(void){

  int N, element, tid;
  int i, j;
  scanf("%d", &N); // matrix dimension
  
  int A[N][N]; // matrix A
  int B[N][N]; // matrix B
  int C[N][N]; // matrix C := AB
  
  // declare elements matrix A
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
      scanf("%d", &element);
      A[i][j] = element;
    }
  }

  // declare elements matrix B
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
      scanf("%d", &element);
      B[i][j] = element;
    }
  }
  
  omp_set_num_threads(N); // set the number of threads

  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(A, B, C, N) private(i, j, tid) 
  { 
    tid = omp_get_thread_num(); // returns the number of the currently executing thread within the team
    #pragma omp for 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
      C[tid][i] = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        //tid = i*n + j;
        C[tid][i] += A[tid][j]*B[j][i];
      }
    }
  }

  // print matrix C 
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
      printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return(0);
}\
```

This is what I get with N = 2 and matrices A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} B = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

C = {{7, random number}, {random number, 22}}

Comment: `omp_set_num_threads(N)` you should really avoid doing this. For large matrices with like 512x512 items, the code will create 512 threads. This is far more than the number of core of modern CPUs so multiple threads will be scheduled on the same cores causing a lot of performance issue. If N is too big, the code will simply crash because the OS cannot create too many threads. Note that allocating arrays based on the content of a non-compile-time variable (VLA like `A[N][N]`) is generally considered as a bad practice.

Comment: Please declare your loop variables in the loop header. That solves many problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand how OMP works, but I get your point. So you recommend to use malloc?

Comment: Yes, but this should not be the thing that cause your OpenMP problem (hence the comment). The comment of VictorEijkhout should be addressed first (possibly by declaring `i` in the loop).

Comment: Did putting the loop variables in the header change the results? It seems like maybe there's somehow a race condition and maybe that's related to the `i` and `j` variables.

Comment: @DanilaBerezin No, still have the problem.

Comment: Try debugging if there is a race condition by checking if more than one thread ever accesses a given C[tid][i]. The other issue maybe around VLAs. I would suggest avoiding using them since they really complicate things. Try statically allocating each array and see if it returns the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at how your code behaves:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(A, B, C, N) private(i, j, tid)
```

Creates N threads, that will all execute the next instructions.

```
#pragma omp for 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
```

Distributes the N iterations to the N threads. With the default omp scheduling, the first thread (tid=0) will execute only the first iteration (i=0), the second thread (tid=1) only the second iteration (i=1), and so on... This means that in the loop body you always get `i = tid`, and consequently `C[tid][i]` addresses the diagonal elements only.

You should obtain the desired result by suppressing `#pragma omp for`, so that the loop on `i` is fully executed by each thread. But as mentioned in the comments, this approach with the creation `N` threads will give poor performances as soon as `N` will be larger then the number of cores (and won't use all the cores when `N` will be smaller than the number of cores).

**EDIT**

The right way is instead to not change the default number of the threads (which is usually equal to the number of physical cores), and define a parallel loop that distribute the rows to the threads:

```
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(A, B, C, N) 
  { 
    #pragma omp for
    for (int k = 0; k < N; i++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        C[k][i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
          C[k][i] += A[k][j]*B[j][i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If N=15 for instance, and with 4 threads:

- the 1st thread will process the iterations for k=0,1,2,3
- the 2nd thread will process the iterations for k=4,5,6,7
- the 3rd thread will process the iterations for k=8,9,10,11
- the 4th thread will process the iterations for k=12,13,14

But note that this code is likely not efficient, even if executed serially without OpenMP. The memory access pattern on `B` in the inner loop is poor, as it addresses non-contiguous elements in memory. For small N it doesn't matter, but for large N it could result in a lot of cache misses, then altered performances.

Comment: This fixed the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, what would you recommend instead of using N as the number of threads?

Comment: @DiegoBravo I have completed the answer

Comment: I realise that this may be merely a simple, easily specified, example to look at, but it's worth pointing out that if you need a parallel matrix multiplication routine you should use a BLAS library, which will include many other optimisations beyond just parallelism, such as vectorisation and cache-blocking. (There are free, as in beer, and even open-source ones available). "The best code is the code you do not have to write" :-)